# TypeScript difference between original object and spreaded object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

there is a riddle about Typescript I cannot understand:

```
const  randomFn = (arg: Record<string, unknown>): string => 'kappa'

export type Values = {
    key: string;
};
const values: Values = {
    key: 'kappa'
}

const { ...spread } = values;

randomFn(values)
randomFn(spread) // produce Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{ transaction: string; }'.(2345)
```

Why is Typescript producing errors for spread object when in my understanding it typing should be the same.
If we inspect the object in playgroud it is exactly the same for TS compiler. Both original and spreaded.

TS version 4.5.4.
Reproduction in [Type Script Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBDBOBDMATEBbAYmGBeGAFIvAOYBcMASgKajwoA808AlmCQDQwCuYA1mBAB3MAD4AlBWZsSeUTADkfRAAcViBQFgAUDuoAPFSHiwoATxXUYANUQAbbtQh4YAbx1w4famalRW7ADcOgC%20wdqgkLAAbvaOEBS2Dk4u7tqeMN6%20ispqGqE6OpHQbjAAdBUQKvDUiCgwIS6xyRDhOkioGNgEzfHi7choWGAEVTV14kA)

EDIT: also doing double spread to make it work again *.*

```
randomFn({...spread}) // NO error
```

Comment: Since spreading isn't always the same type, it won't work automatically, but you can coerce this one with `randomFn(spread as Values);`

Comment: It does not need to be of the same type, required one is `Record<string, unknown>` . Any subset of keys from spread should meet this requirement even empty object in the worst case.

Comment: This is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021 I think

Comment: It's a design limitation of TypeScript, as shown in the above linked issue.  Does that answer your question? If so I can write up an answer here; if not, can you tell me what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that's kind of info i was looking for! It answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of a design limitation of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#42021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021) for details.  When you use a rest element in an object destructuring assignment, TypeScript unfortunately does not copy an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) into the type of the new variable.  Nor does it allow the variable to have an [implicit index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) (although [I'm not sure why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021#issuecomment-1047172066)).

Your `Values` type alias is allowed to have an implicit index signature (if you made it an `interface` then it wouldn't either, see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)), so it is considered assignable to `Record<string, unknown>` (which is equivalent to `{[k: string]: unknown}`, a type with a string index signature).  But `spread`, as a rest-destructured variable, is not, and therefore it fails.

You noticed that doing a second rest destructuring *does* work, so presumably there's something weird about how object types get marked to allow or disallow implicit index signatures.  This is also [noted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021#issuecomment-791997806) in microsoft/TypeScript#42021, although without explanation.

So unfortunately there's not a very satisfying answer to be had right now, unless more activity happens in microsoft/TypeScript#42021.

Answer (score 1):

Spreading loses the type because it has no guarantee that the type of the spread object is the same. Consider this:

```
const { excluded, ...rest } = object;
```

Clearly `rest` can't be the same type as `object`; there is a key missing!

You can also think of it like this:

```
const [excluded, ...rest] = array;
```

That's why `spread` is not type `Values`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ok I got the point but why does it no longer matches the type of function argument of `Record<string, unknown>`?

Comment: I also think that in this example you are not correct, if no key is taken away from the object during spread it stays the same type.

Take a look:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBDBOBDMATEBbAYmGBeGAFIvAOYBcMAaogDYCuAphAJQXTwCWYJeAfDAHIA1ogAOoxAICwAKFkMAHqJDxYUAJ6iGVWowh4YAb1lw4QhurZRO3ANyyAvvZmhIsAG66mFavSYHjGVMYc0tBEXFJR1lZV2gjGAA6ZIhReAZEFBgHA08-CGdZJFQMbAI8vWYi5DQsMAJU9MzmIA

Comment: It doesn't look like this answer addresses the question; can you explain the relevance?  It seems like you're talking about incomplete copies not being the same type as the original, but the question is not obviously about incomplete copies.  It's as if the question is "why can I keep a dog as a pet but not a wolf? Aren't they the same species?" and the answer is "No, a dog is not a wolf.  After all, a dog has four legs, but a wolf only has three (if you remove one of its legs)."  What am I missing?